# Как подключиться к localhost:3000 на ноутбуке с планшета ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, remote-debugging

Я запуская локальный сервер, он висит на localhost:3000.
И через браузер я на него захожу.

Как мне подключиться к нему с планшета ipad?
То есть посмотреть как будет работать система на планшете.

Comment: Вместо *localhost* укажите IP адрес устройства на котором он запущен.

Comment: Да, всё просто) Совсем забыл про общую сеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно узнать локальный ip ноутбука ( notebook_ip). и подключить планшет к той-же сети, к которой подключён ноутбук. Далее...
Если на ноуте Windows:
  В командной строке набираем:
    `ipconfig`
Если на ноуте MacOS:
  В терминале набираем:
    `ifconfig`
Если на ноуте Linux:
  В консоли набираем:
    `ip addr`
После того, как выяснили локальный ip ноута, в браузере на планшете набираем:
    notebook_ip:3000

> **Почему вышеописанный способ может не сработать.**
>
> ---
>
> 1.) Если сервер запущен просто на localhost. То есть сервер слушает только адрес 127.0.0.1 и на запросы приходящие на ip локальной сети ему пофиг.
>
> ---
>
> 2.) Если на ноутбуке поднят фаервол блокирующий порт подключения (в данном конкретном случае 3000).

---

Это вкратце. Вариантов может быть масса. Но перечисленные наиболее вероятны.